# set cookie variable in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to set a cookie in jquery using :

```
 $( "a.Edit" ) .click(function() { 
$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog( "open" );
 var un=$(this ).text();
 $.cookie("test", un);
  });
```

but when i use it after that `<?php echo $_COOKIE['test'] ?>` it wont work the cookie is still not set

any help please

thanks in advance

Comment: cookie from javascript is different than from PHP ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [jquery_cookie()](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin for this.

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Where `the_cookie` is the name of your cookie. and where `the_value` of your cookie is the value/function it has to do.
`expires 7` means that the cookie wil expire in 7 days (one week)
`Path` isn't nessesary,

> Define the path where the cookie is valid. By default the path of the
>   cookie is the path of the page where the cookie was created (standard
>   browser behavior). If you want to make it available for instance
>   across the entire domain use path: '/'. Default: path of page where
>   the cookie was created.

You can remove the cookie using:

```
$.removeCookie('the_cookie');
```

you can read the cookie using:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie');
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$.cookie("example", "foo", { expires: 7 });
```

[Source](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set the cookie in PHP entirely without jQuery at all..

..however...

It appears you are using jQuery in [this way.](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/)

What may be causing a problem is a few things:

a) $(this).val() possibly might be returning NULL.

b) You are not setting the path and expiration on the cookie. 
       If you have subdirectories it is normally good to set a **master cookie** that is the root path '/'.

To read your cookie using PHP, try this...

```
 $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
```

Can be possible duplicate of [Get the cookie value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778109/get-the-cookie-value-in-php)