# Can't get cookie value php

Tags: php, cookies

I can't get cookie values. My cookie is available in browser. When I set cookie it will show and working but after few hour I can't get any response from cookies.

```
$cookie_name = "token";
$cookie_value = $value;
setcookie($cookie_name);
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", '.example.com');

echo $_COOKIE[token];
```

Comment: When you create the cookie, is this available ? check if it's expired

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the cookie value in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778109/get-the-cookie-value-in-php)

Comment: Can you use `var_dump` on the cookies?

Comment: Yes when i create cookie its working, I already try var_dump and print_r

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the quotes around the cookie name

```
$cookie_name = "token";
$cookie_value = $value;
setcookie($cookie_name);
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", '.example.com');

echo $_COOKIE['token']; //[token] > ['token']
```

Answer (score 0):

You've just forgot the quotes when referenced `token`. If you have it as a variable, why don't you use it?

```
$cookie_name = "token";
$cookie_value = $value;
setcookie($cookie_name);
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), "/", '.example.com');

echo $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
```

Comment: i got blank response in print_r . quotes doesn't change anything

Comment: Could you please check cookies in your browser? Can you find your `token` cookie?

Comment: Yes i can see cookie in browser And its not expired.

Comment: @goluwes Are you aware that you cannot read cookies in the very same run when you're setting them? I bet you can read them when you're refreshing the page (just try to remove `setcookie`-part) and read the cookie.

Comment: I set cookie on different page and i read it on different page. I already mention that. It will stop working after few hours. That mean when it created its working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
echo $_COOKIE[token];
```

with this:

```
echo $_COOKIE['token'];
```

You have not added quotes with cookie name.